# Javascript: How may I call a function of an external website?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I would like to write a simple script to open a Website and call a function that is part of a linked .js-file.

To be more precise, I want to open a SharePoint, invoke the function that is used to open the folder in windows explorer and close the website again.
For some reason, I may not open the folder directly in explorer unless I had it done this way at least once during the active windows session...

How may I do this?

So far, I tried the following:

```
var IE = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
var WSH = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
IE.visible = true;
IE.navigate("https://mysharepoint.com/Folder");
WSH.PopUp("Click to fire function");
//the following line throws an error, because the function is unknown...
IE.Document.defaultView.setTimeout(NavigateHttpFolder, 0, "https://mysharepoint.com/Folder", "_blank");

//the following line does not throw an error, but nothing happens either..
IE.Document.defaultView.setTimeout(function(){NavigateHttpFolder("https://mysharepoint.com/Folder", "_blank");}, 0);
```

However, when I open my Sharepoint and type the following line into the addressbar it does exactly what I want to achieve and it opens the folder...

`javascript:NavigateHttpFolder("https://mysharepoint.com/Folder", "_blank");`

Could you please help me? I simply cannot find a way to get this to work.

UPDATE: Now it worked suddenly! I tried it the following way before but it didn't do anything until now (???)...

```
IE.Navigate('javascript:NavigateHttpFolder("https://mysharepoint.com/Folder", "_blank");');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include script with path to external website

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.external.com/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to tell, that I don't want to invoke this function from some HTML-application. I want to put a .JS-file into my startup folder to open the sharepoint path actually.